# What's the time complexity of sorting a list of objects with two properties?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Suppose I have a class:
`

```
public class Interval {
    int start;
    int end;
    Interval() { start = 0; end = 0; }
    Interval(int s, int e) { start = s; end = e; }
}
```

`

I would like to sort a list of intervals with Collections.sort() like this:

```
Collections.sort(intervals, new Comparator<Interval>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Interval o1, Interval o2) {
        if (o1.start == o2.start) {
            return o1.end - o2.end;
        }
        else {
            return o1.start - o2.start;
        }
    }
});
```

I know that sorting an array with the built-in sorting function takes O(nlogn) time, and the question is if I am sorting a list of objects with two properties, what is the time complexity of sorting this list? Thanks!!

Comment: It is the same complexity `(O n* log(n))` .  An extra `if` statement isn't going to turn a logarithmic sort into a quadtratic one.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification!! I understand now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's not accurate. I think you meant that the `else` statement adds no cost, but extra `if` statements would - squaring the cost with every new condition.

Comment: Note that it's a good habit to use `Integer.compare(a, b)` rather than the `a - b` idiom, since the latter doesn't work when the difference between a and b is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. (Such as when comparing -1 and Integer.MAX_VALUE).

Comment: @mohsenmadi So what is the Big O notation for the extra if statement?  It is O(1), and that is overwhelmed by the overall algorithm complexity.

Comment: I think something is missing. Suppose we are comparing `n` objects with `m` properties each, and that comparison is nested, so for every comparison of the `n` objects, we may have to perform other `m` comparisons on the properties to settle the score. That's `n * m`. The sorting algorithm we agree it's `O(n log n)`. Product? `O(m * n * log n)` (and not `O(n * m * n * log n)`. How's that?

Comment: @mohsenmadi: But *m* is a constant (since the number of properties is baked into the program, and not a property of its inputs), so O(*m* *n* log *n*) is the same as O(*n* log *n*).

Comment: True! Where are my big O manners huh? Seems I forgot them a bit. But, isn't there something about big Os being offset and misleading when dealing with big constants? I mean, what if we're comparing 10 objects, but each comes with a million properties? Now `n log n` is hardly 30, but the real cost is there in about 30 * 10 million, right? Missing something...

Comment: To answer my own comment: yea yea yea, but `n` is the variable here, and as `n` gets awfully large, `m` will be insignificant. Got it :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@PaulMcKenzie's brief answer in comments is on the right track, but the full answer to your question is more subtle.

Many people do what you've done and confuse time with other measures of efficiency. What's correct in nearly all cases when someone says a "sort is O(n log n)" is that *the number of **comparisons*** is O(n log n).

I'm not trying to be pedantic. Sloppy analysis can make big problems in practice. You can't claim that any sort runs in O(n log n) ***time*** without a raft of additional statements about the data and the machine where the algorithm is running. Research papers usually do this by giving a standard machine model used for their analysis. The model states the time required for low level operations - memory access, arithmetic, and comparisons, for example.

In your case, each object comparison requires a constant number (2) of value comparisons. So long as value comparison itself is constant time -- true in practice for fixed-width integers -- O(n log n) is an accurate way to express run time.

However, something as simple as string sorting changes this picture. String comparison itself has a variable cost. It depends on string length! So sorting strings with a "good" sorting algorithm is O(nk log n), where k is the length of strings.

Ditto if you're sorting variable-length numbers (java `BigInteger`s for example).

Sorting is also sensitive to copy costs. Even if you can compare objects in constant time, sort time will depend on how big they are. Algorithms differ in how many times objects need to be moved in memory. Some accept more comparisons in order to do less copying.  An implementation detail: sorting pointers vs. objects can change asymptotic run time - a space for time trade.

But even this has complications. After you've sorted pointers, touching the sorted elements in order hops around memory in arbitrary order. This can cause terrible memory hierarchy (cache) performance. Analysis that incorporates memory characteristics is a big topic in itself.

Answer (score 0):

The big O notation actually do neglect the least contributing factors

for example if you complexity is `n+1`, `n` will be used and the `1` neglected.

So that answer is the same `n * log(n)`.
As your code just adds one more statement, which will be translated into one instruction.

Answer (score -1):

It should read the Collection.sort() [Link here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

**This algorithm guaranteed n log(n) performance.**

Note: Comparator does't change the its complexity rather than using Loops

Comment: The comparator *can* absolutely change the complexity of the whole algorithm, if the algorithm used to compare depends on the number of elements being compared. But that's not the case here, the comparison itself is O(1).

Comment: Yes ur correct but iam talking above algoritham only ..Thank you @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: Of course a comparison can cause the complexity to change if that comparison leads to another set of loops over the dataset.  That isn't the case here.

Comment: This discussion is an example if what my answer is talking about. Comparison cost matters. So do copy costs.

Comment: Sorry i am mistaken